# sqlalchemy one-to-many without unique constraint

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to model the following relationship:

- There are stops, and many stops can have the same name.
- There are translations, and multiple translations use the same stop name (but different languages). So that one stop name could be translated to many languages.

Since the stop_name is not unique among stops, sqlaclhemy+postgres don't like it when I try to create a one-to-many relationship (see below). But this is not exactly one-to-many. What I want, when I access stop.translations, is to get all of the translations that match this query: `SELECT * from translation WHERE translation.stop_name == stop.stop_name`. So I accept the actual many-to-many relationship here, but want to hide it from my users, to make it look like one-to-many.

I thought of using hybrid attributes, but they seem to be scalar only, so that's not really an option. I probably did a bad job trying to prefill a many-to-many relationship, because that took forever and timedout.

Some context: this is part of `pygtfs`, but here is the minimal example of when this goes wrong. When I run the following script:

```
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.orm
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Unicode
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Stop(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stop'
    stop_id = Column(Unicode, primary_key=True)
    stop_name = Column(Unicode)

    # What I'd like:
    translations = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Translation', viewonly=True,
            primaryjoin="stop.c.stop_name==translation.c.stop_name")

class Translation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'translation'
    stop_name = Column(Unicode, primary_key=True)
    lang = Column(Unicode, primary_key=True)
    translation = Column(Unicode)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432")
    Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    session = Session()
    session.add(Stop(stop_id="hrld", stop_name="Herald Square"))
```

I get:

```
[...]
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join condition 'stop.stop_name = translation.stop_name' on relationship Stop.translations.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation.
```

What can I do to map this in sqlaclhemy?

[edit after a comment]:
If I add a ForeignKey, it fails, because stop_name is not unique (and I don't want it to be unique!):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "translation"
[SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE stop (\n\tstop_id VARCHAR NOT NULL, \n\tstop_name VARCHAR, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (stop_id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(stop_name) REFERENCES translation (stop_name)\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: change `stop_name = Column(Unicode)` to `stop_name = Column(Unicode, db.ForeignKey('translation.stop_name'), index=True)`

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but that doesn't work because of stop_name is not unique. I just recreated it, getting:

    sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "translation"
 [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE stop (\n\tstop_id VARCHAR NOT NULL, \n\tstop_name VARCHAR, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (stop_id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(stop_name) REFERENCES translation (stop_name)\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Comment: so you need to go with a many-to-many relation but restrict them in your program.